# LINQ dynamic orderby from querystring

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

```
public static IList<ForumTopicReply> getTopicRepliesByTopicId(int forumId, int categoryId, int topicId, string orderBy)
{
    var ctx = new dataContext();

    IList<ForumTopicReply> forumTopicReplies = (from r in ctx.ForumTopicReplies
                                                where r.ForumId == forumId && r.ForumCategoryId == categoryId && r.ForumTopicId == topicId
                                                orderby r.DateCreated descending
                                                select r).ToList();
    return forumTopicReplies;
}
```

Basically I just want to change orderby based on what the querystring is set to, so fx.: /ViewTopic.aspx?sort=dateOldest

How can I then change "orderby r.Id" to "orderby r.dateCreated" in my code? I am already passing the parameter in, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = ...;
switch(yourvar)
{
  case "oldest":
    query=query.OrderBy(x=>x.Age); break;
  case "alpha":
    query=query.OrderBy(x=>x.Name); break;
}
```